# BigCommerce Displaying Brands on Homepage (Stencil)

Tags: handlebars.js, bigcommerce, yaml-front-matter

I need to display a *collection of brands on the home page* of a BigCommerce theme. The theme is using Stencil and Handlebars.js. My Front-matter block at the top of the page is as follows:

**YAML** at the top of the page.

```
---
carousel: true
products:
  new:
    limit: {{theme_settings.home-new-products}}
  featured:
    limit: {{theme_settings.home-featured-products}}
  top_sellers:
    limit: {{theme_settings.home-top-selling-products}}
blog:
  recent_posts:
    limit: 3
    summary: {{theme_settings.home-blog-summary-length}}
brands:
  limit: {{theme_settings.brands-count}}
---
```

**Handlebars.js** further down on the home page.

```
<ul class="brand-items-list">
    {{#each brands}}
      <li class="brand-item {{#unless image}}no-brand-image{{/unless}}">
        {{#if image}}
          <figure class="brand-item-image-container">
            <a href="{{url}}">
              <img
                class="brant-item-image brand-name"
                src="{{getImage image 'thumb'}}"
                alt="{{name}}"
              >
              <span class="brand-name">{{name}}</span>
            </a>
          </figure>
        {{else}}
          <a class="brand-item-title" href="{{url}}">
            <span class="brand-name">{{name}}</span>
          </a>
        {{/if}}
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
```

From my understanding, *brands* should return a collection of brand objects that can be iterated through on any page. [BigCommerce Front-Matter Documentation](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/front-matter-variables#Front-ref-brandlist)

The problem I'm having is that {{ brands }} is empty when used on the home page.

Comment: {{brands}} is available only in the context of brands.html, but {{shop_by_brand}} can be used globally to display a list of brands. What kind of presentation are you trying to achieve with the brands on the homepage?

Comment: Thank you for the help! I need to display the brand images on the homepage. Was the context availability of {{brands}} mentioned in the docs or did I just miss it?

Comment: Glad to help :) There are a couple of places in the docs that can indicate the context in which an object can be called. In the front matter reference, all of the objects in the top `Global Objects` table can be invoked on all pages: https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/front-matter-variables. The Stencil Object Model reference will also list the templates that call a particular object: https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/brand-resources. Another good tool is the debug bar (shows which objects are currently available): https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/testingdebugging-themes

Comment: You could probably use Stencil utils to make an ajax request to the brand page and scrape the brand images from there, but it might be easier just to hard-code the logos in

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the detailed answer!